# How do I fill a list with all the world's phone prefixes in Dart on Flutter?

Tags: json, regex, flutter, validation, dart

I'd like to implement an app with Dart on Flutter. I'm on my first approach with this new language and for the first time I meet this problem.
My app must necessarily work with a mobile phone number. I would like to see a ban on the insertion of unse prefixed telephone numbers or, alternatively, the typing of a number with more digits than expected. For example, in Italy the figures after +39 (0039) are at most 10. I probably thought I'd separate the two parts to make it easier to distinguish between lengths (one field where you select the country and another that allows you to enter the number).
Is there, as you know, a JSON that contains exactly: - the prefix of each state, - the length of the telephone number (excluding prefix), - name, *flag and *sigla (Italy, green-white-red, IT)?
Sifting through the web a little bit, I saw that flutter should actually provide already in itself with .demoTextFieldEnterITPhoneNumber, through GalleryLocalizations to do such a job, but I didn't quite understand if it bothers to control a particular regular expression for each nation or not. Could I copy and paste a number for example? Will nationality be automatically recognized?
In the end I think that such a control, so deep, is not possible so I would just need this, so make two fields, one with a list, which at the choice automatically fills in depending on the selected prefix, and a field on which the user types his number: in case of copied and pasted number check if that string also contains a +prefix.

Thank you very much, I need a lot, since my app will mainly revolve around a correct value for this field. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [international_phone_input](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/international_phone_input) or [country_code_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/country_code_picker) flutter package. They are quite easy to implement

Comment: Thanks! I will try this approach :)